# Get offset from datetime string and apply to a new date object

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, object, momentjs

I have a datetime string returned from my backend like this:

```
2018-12-30T20:00:00-05:00
```

I am trying to get the offset from this datetime string and apply it to a new Date object.

When I do that... I get the clients timezone date instead of the one I would like.

```
var time = "2018-12-30T20:00:00-05:00"
new Date(time)
```

I don't mind leveraging momentjs or any other library in JS but I am trying to do this in my front-end.

**UPDATE**

if the date returned from my backend has -05:00 as the offset... then when I create a date object in the front end... it should have the same offset

For example:

```
2018-12-31T10:00:00-05:00
```

Comment: Your question is a little vague because there is more than one way to interpret applying an offset to a date — you could convert it to a new absolute time, you could keep the absolute time the same, but apply a new offset, etc. It would help if you gave an example of a correct before and after date/time.

Comment: @MarkMeyer added an example

Comment: did you try to use ordinary way?

Comment: @Jin yes but it goes with the clients offset instead of using the -5 offset https://jsfiddle.net/f8hqwb1k/

Comment: then what is your expected result?
can you write an example?
with your above text

Comment: I am seeing the new date object in central time but it should be in eastern time since I am using -5 @Jin

Comment: your result would be `Dec 30, 2018, 15:00:00` (regarding offset), right?

Comment: No, since -5 is the timezone offset for ET... I want my date to be converted to ET.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're willing to use `moment` you can easily pull the offset from the date/time with `utcOffset`.  You can use the same function to apply the offset to the new date/time. Here are two moment objects that represent the same time, but with different offsets. This converts the second to the offset of the first without changing the absolute time:

```js
var time = "2018-12-30T10:00:00-05:00"
let m = moment.parseZone(time)
let offset = m.utcOffset()
console.log("original: ", m.format(), "Offset:", offset)

// same time as m but -1 ofset
let m2 = moment.parseZone("2018-12-30T14:00:00-01:00")
console.log("m2 original: ", m2.format())

// change offset
m2.utcOffset(offset)
console.log("m2 converted: ", m2.format())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.23/moment-timezone-with-data-2012-2022.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to get the timezone from the string, the convert it to an ECMAScript offset and use it to format a string with the required offset.

There are already answers on SO to do the above, but here's an answer anyway.

E.g.

```js
/* Returns offset, uses match to allow for decimal seconds in timestamp
** @param {string} s - ECMAScript formatted datetime string with offset
**                    in the format YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss+/-HH:mm or Z
** @returns {string} - offset part of string, i.e. +/-HH:mm or Z
*/
function getOffset(s) {
  return offset = (s.match(/z$|[+\-]\d\d:\d\d$/i) || [])[0];
}

/* Convert offset in +/-HH:mm format or Z to ECMAScript offset
** @param {string} offset - in +/-HH:mm format or Z
** @returns {number} - ECMSCript offset in minutes, i.e. -ve east, +ve west
*/
function offsetToMins(offset) {
  // Deal with Z or z
  if (/z/i.test(offset)) return 0;
  // Deal +/-HH:mm
  var sign = /^-/.test(offset)? '1':'-1';
  var [h, m] = offset.slice(-5).split(':');
  return sign * h * 60 + +m; 
}

/* Format date with offset
** @param {Date} date - date to format
** @param {string} offset - ECMASCript offset string, 
**                          e.g. -05:00, Z
** @returns {string} ISO 8601 formatted string with
** specified offset
*/
function adjustToOffset(date, offset) {
  var o = offsetToMins(offset);
  var d = new Date(+date);
  d.setUTCMinutes(d.getUTCMinutes() - o);
  return d.toISOString().replace('Z', offset);
}

// Source string
var s = '2018-12-30T20:00:00-05:00';

// Get offset
var offset = getOffset(s);

// Make sure it's ok
if (typeof offset == 'undefined') {
  console.log('offset not found');

// Otherwise, show current time with specified offset
} else {
  console.log(adjustToOffset(new Date(), offset));
}
```

Note that typical ISO 8601 offsets don't have a colon, i.e. they're usually ±HHmm.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very rough example of how to approach this with pure JS, for those that get here and don't want to use Moment JS:

```js
const d = new Date("2018-12-30T20:00:00-05:00");
const epochTimeDate = d.getTime(); // Get milliseconds since Unix Epoch
const localTZOffsetMilliseconds = d.getTimezoneOffset() * (60 * 1000); // Convert minutes to milliseconds
const msCoefficient = (60 * 60 * 1000);
const newTZOffsetHours = -3; // UTC -3

const newTZTime = new Date(epochTimeDate - (-1*(newTZOffsetHours*msCoefficient))); // The -1 reverses the confusing behavior of the browser spec which is the opposite of the actual offset
console.log(newTZTime.toISOString().replace(/T|Z/g,' ')+"(UTC "+newTZOffsetHours+")");
```

The better way to output would be to implement your own function that displays the date using the getter functions for hours, minutes, etc.  I'm not sure if the `.toISOString()` is standard but it works in Chrome.

Comment: I hear ISOString has cross browser compatibility issues but this is still a good answer

Comment: You don't need to mess around with milliseconds like that, just adjust the UTC minutes.